# using angular to modify css class properties

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a css class 'suggestions-list'in which I have `height: initial;` in my angularjs code in a condition I want to change `height: inherit;` how can I modify this css class using angular?

in my CSS file I have :

```
.suggestions-list {
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 35px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: initial;
    width: 250px;
    border-bottom: 50px;
}
```

and this is my HTML:

```
<ul class="suggestions-list" ng-show="myVar">
     <li ng-repeat="suggestion in suggestions track by $index" ng-class="{active : selectedIndex === $index}" ng-click="AssignValueAndHide($index)">{{suggestion}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is the problem you have now?

Comment: how can I modify this css class using angular?

Comment: You can do it like this: `ng-class="{active : selectedIndex === $index}"`

Comment: but how? would you please help me in writing it?

Comment: With above class `active` will be set if `selectedIndex === $index` is true. If it doesn't happen in your case, it means that `selectedIndex === $index` is `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-style`

```
<div ng-style="{height: (condition?'initial':'inherit')}"></div>
```

Comment: This condition is set in my angular js code. so how can I set it from here?

Comment: @user3122648 what condition exactly do you mean? condition in ng-style can accept expression!

Comment: I', trying to do it in my Javascript code. so 
<div ng-style="{height:myStyle}"></div> that I want to chaneg it from Js. in which myStyle is a scope.

Comment: This is pretty bad solution. Avoid using ngStyle for such things. ngClass should be used here.

Comment: So would you pelase help me using it? becasue if I use ng-class how can I apply my css class?